# Website best way to navigate through pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm new in Javascript and I am practising making my own website.
I would like an advice which is the best way to navigate through pages.
I have

- index.html
- pages/home.html
- pages/about.html
- pages/contact.html

The easiest way is the link to each page but this would mean that I need to reply the same template to each page by coping-paste the same code all the time (and I don't think it is really smart). Moreover the URL of my website will be, for example, [www.mysite.con/pages/about.html](http://www.mysite.con/pages/about.html)
and it is not very elegant; I would like more something like [www.mysite.com/about](http://www.mysite.com/about) (without ".html").

I also tried using load() function from JQuery so that I have my index page

```
<div id="pageContentHere"></div>
```

and through JQuery I load page content into the div; this is very usefull because so I only write one template but my URL will always be [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and if someone wants to go directly to the about page there will be no URL to link that.

Could you please suggest me how would you do in a smarter way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I want to thank everyone for the answers which have been really usefull;
At the end I'm using this solution which, I believe, is a good compromise:

I put all pages into one and via Javascript I hide them all and showing only the one I need:

(I can actually fill the content of the pages divs via JQuery or AngularJS. They don't need to be phisically in the same file).

HTML

```
<div id="allPages">
    <div id="MainPage" class="page" style="background:red">
    Home page
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#SecondPage">Go to second page</a>
        <li><a href="#ThirdPage">Go to third page</a>
        <li><a href="#ForthPage">Go to forth page</a>
    </ul>
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="SecondPage" class="page" style="background:yellow">
    This is second page
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#MainPage">Go to home page</a>
        <li><a href="#ThirdPage">Go to third page</a>
        <li><a href="#ForthPage">Go to forth page</a>
    </ul>


    </div>
    
    <div id="ThirdPage" class="page" style="background:blue">
    This is third page
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#MainPage">Go to home page</a>
        <li><a href="#SecondPage">Go to second page</a>
        <li><a href="#ForthPage">Go to forth page</a>
    </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div id="ForthPage" class="page" style="background:green">
    This is forth page
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#MainPage">Go to home page</a>
        <li><a href="#SecondPage">Go to second page</a>
        <li><a href="#ThirdPage">Go to forth page</a>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#allPages {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    /* display: flex; */
    height: 100%;
}

.page {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var url;
    url = getUrl();
    goToClickedPage(url)
    
    $("#allPages ul li a").click(function(){
        var linkTo;
        /*
        I cannot get the id from getUrl() because when I click I'm still on the "previous page". So I must get the attribute from the link
        */


        linkTo = $(this).attr("href");
        goToClickedPage(linkTo);
    });

});

function getUrl(){
    /*
    From here I get the focused page by the url.
    The URL will be something like www.mysite.com/#SecondPage
    location.hash will return me, in this case '#SecondPage' which is exactly the id of the page I want to go.
    The problem will be for the homepage which will only be www.mysite.com which will return an empty string. In this case I check and, if I'm in homepage, I set manually the URL to be like the Id of the homepage
    */


    var url;
    url = ($(location.hash).length===0) ? "#MainPage":location.hash;
    console.log(url);
    return url;
}

function goToClickedPage(url){

/*
From here I hide all pages except the one with the URL id I what to see
*/
    $("#allPages .page").hide();
    $(url).show();
}
```

I know it's not the most elegant way but I hope it might be helpful for someone.
If you have any tips are ofcourse welcome

Answer (score -1):

First, bravo to you for noticing some of the issues in your current implementation. One of the more recent approaches to this (though one might consider heavyweight) is the idea of Single Page Applications. [React](https://reactjs.org/) is an example of an SPA framework, along with [GatsbyJS](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/), which is likely a better fit for a static site like yours. They offer solutions for both issues you mention, like client-side routing and reusable components.

You can also look into JavaScript templating engines as well (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16327719/3813411) answer).